# How to make a reference type property "readonly"

Tags: c#, properties, encapsulation, readonly

I have a class `Bar` with a private field containing the reference type `Foo`. I would like to expose `Foo` in a public property, but I do not want the consumers of the property to be able to alter `Foo`... It should however be alterable internally by `Bar`, i.e. I can't make the field `readonly`.

So what I would like is:

```
      private _Foo;

      public Foo 
      { 
         get { return readonly _Foo; } 
      }
```

...which is of course not valid. I could just return a clone of `Foo` (assumming that it is `IClonable`), but this is not obvious to the consumer. Should I change the name of the property to `FooCopy`?? Should it be a `GetCopyOfFoo` method instead? What would you consider best practice?   Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like you're after the equivalent of "const" from C++. This doesn't exist in C#. There's no way of indicating that consumers can't modify the properties of an object, but something else can (assuming the mutating members are public, of course).

You could return a clone of the Foo as suggested, or possibly a *view* onto the Foo, as [ReadOnlyCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) does for collections. Of course if you could make `Foo` an immutable type, that would make life simpler...

Note that there's a big difference between making the *field* readonly and making the object itself immutable.

Currently, the type itself could change things in both ways. It could do:

```
_Foo = new Foo(...);
```

*or*

```
_Foo.SomeProperty = newValue;
```

If it only needs to be able to do the second, the field could be readonly but you still have the problem of people fetching the property being able to mutate the object. If it only needs to do the first, and actually `Foo` is either already immutable or could be made immutable, you can just provide a property which only has the "getter" and you'll be fine.

It's *very important* that you understand the difference between changing the value of the field (to make it refer to a different instance) and changing the contents of the object that the field refers to.

Comment: What is a view in this context? An interface or wrapper?

Comment: ...and absolutely agree on the value/contents of reference distinction. Unfortunately I need to do both.

Comment: See my comment for what I think he means by view.

Comment: @jon: Just curious Jon, why can't we have a private set property here ? 'public Foo 
      { 
         get { return _Foo; }  private set { _Foo = value;}

      }
'

or am I missing something here ?

Comment: @Ram: I don't see what that would accomplish. The idea is to expose a read-only view of Foo - not just the variable holding it, but the object itself.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there's no easy way around this in C# at the moment. You could extract the "read only part" of `Foo` in an interface and let your property return that instead of `Foo`.

Comment: Less than ideal, because the interface could still be cast to a Foo.

Comment: I agree - but you're at least revealing your intentions to the caller.

Comment: @rossfabricant: Decide whether you want to protect against Murphy or Machiavelli. Downcasting to Foo is Machiavellan. You can't design to protect against ill will, only against mistakes.

Comment: Good point, and with reflection available to the caller, there's very little you can do against Machiavelli anyway. But in any case a const modifier would be better.

Comment: @pontus gagge-Awesome point.  Wish I could upvote your comment more.

Answer (score 2):

Making a copy, a `ReadOnlyCollection`, or having `Foo` be immutable are usually the three best routes, as you've already speculated.

I sometimes favor methods instead of properties whenever I'm doing anything more significant than simply returning the underlying field, depending on how much work is involved. Methods imply that something is going on and raise more of a flag for consumers when they're using your API.

Answer (score 1):

"Cloning" the Foo objects you receive and give back out is a normal practice called **defensive copying**. Unless there is some unseen side-effect to cloning that will be visible to the user, there is absolutely no reason to NOT do this. It is often the only way to protect your classes' internal private data, especially in C# or Java, where the C++ idea of `const` is not available. (IE, it must be done in order to properly create truly immutable objects in these two languages.)

Just to clarify, possible side effects would be things like your user (reasonably) expecting that the original object be returned, or some resource being held by Foo that will not be cloned correctly. (In which case, what is it doing implementing IClonable?!)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want anyone to mess with your state...don't expose it!  As others have said, if something needs to view your internal state, provide an immutable representation of it.  Alternatively, get clients to tell *you* to do something (Google for "tell don't ask"), instead of doing it themselves.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify Jon Skeet's comment you can make a view, that is an immutable wrapper class for the mutable Foo. Here's an example:

```
class Foo{
 public string A{get; set;}
 public string B{get; set;}
 //...
}

class ReadOnlyFoo{
  Foo foo; 
  public string A { get { return foo.A; }}
  public string B { get { return foo.B; }}
}
```

Comment: This only works if the properties of Foo are value types. If Foo has a ref type property foo.Obj, then the caller can still alter the object at will (although not set it to a new object, see John Skeet's remarks above). So it is not really immutable.

Comment: You could have ReadOnlyFoo have a property that returns a ReadOnlyBar.

Comment: ...and so on ad infinitum... Seems like an awful lot of overhead.

Comment: @Joel: That's what you get for having a deeply mutable type, basically. @rossfabricant: Yes, that's exactly what I meant, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can actually reproduce the behaviour of C++ const in C# - you just have to do it manually.

Whatever `Foo` is, the only way the caller can modify its state is by calling methods on it or setting properties.

For example, `Foo` is of type `FooClass`:

```
class FooClass
{
    public void MutateMyStateYouBadBoy() { ... }

    public string Message
    {
        get { ... }
        set { ... }
    }
}
```

So in your case, you're happy for them to get the `Message` property, but not set it, and you're definitely not happy about them calling that method.

So define an interface describing what they're allowed to do:

```
interface IFooConst
{
    public string Message
    {
        get { ... }
    }
}
```

We've left out the mutating method and only left in the getter on the property.

Then add that interface to the base list of `FooClass`.

Now in your class with the `Foo` property, you have a field:

```
private FooClass _foo;
```

And a property getter:

```
public IFooConst Foo
{
    get { return _foo; }
}
```

This basically reproduces by hand precisely what the C++ `const` keyword would do automatically. In psuedo-C++ terms, a reference of type `const Foo &` is like an automatically generated type that only includes those members of `Foo` that were marked as `const` members. Translating this into some theoretical future version of C#, you'd declare `FooClass` like this:

```
class FooClass
{
    public void MutateMyStateYouBadBoy() { ... }

    public string Message
    {
        get const { ... }
        set { ... }
    }
}
```

Really all I've done is merged the information in `IFooConst` back into `FooClass`, by tagging the one safe member with a new `const` keyword. So in a way, adding a const keyword wouldn't add much to the language besides a formal approach to this pattern.

Then if you had a `const` reference to a `FooClass` object:

```
const FooClass f = GetMeAFooClass();
```

You would only be able to call the const members on `f`.

Note that if the `FooClass` definition is public, the caller could cast an `IFooConst` into a `FooClass`. But they can do that in C++ too - it's called "casting away `const`" and involves a special operator called `const_cast<T>(const T &)`.

There's also the issue of interfaces not being very easy to evolve between versions of your product. If a third party may implement an interface you define (which they are free to do if they can see it), then you can't add new methods to it in future versions without requiring others to recompile their code. But that's only a problem if you are writing an extensible library for others to build on. Maybe a built-in `const` feature would solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about similar security things. There is probably a way. Quite clear  but not short. The general idea is quite simple. However I always found some ways around so never tested it. But you could check it - maybe it will work for you.

This is pseudo code, but I hope idea behind it is clear

```
public delegate void OnlyRuller(string s1, string s2);
public delegate void RullerCoronation(OnlyRuller d);

class Foo {
  private Foo();
  public Foo(RullerCoronation followMyOrders) {
     followMyOrders(SetMe);
  }

  private SetMe(string whatToSet, string whitWhatValue) {
     //lot of unclear but private code
  }
}
```

So in class which creates this property you have access to SetMe method, but it's still private so except for creator Foo looks unmutable.

Still for anything bigger than few properties this will probably became soon super mess - that's why I always preferred other ways of encapsulation. However if it's super important for you to not allow the client to change Foo, than this is one alternative.

However, as I said, this is only theory.