# Prevent other classes from altering a list in a class

Tags: c#

If I have a class that contains, for example, a List<string> and I want other classes to be able to see the list but not *set* it, I can declare

```
public class SomeClass()
{
    public List<string> SomeList { get; }
}
```

This will allow another class to access SomeList and not set it.

However, although the calling class can't *set* the list, it can add or remove elements. How do I prevent that? I guess I could use a field and return a copy of the List instead of using a property, but that just doesn't feel right.

(This should be very simple but I must be missing something....)

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619396/read-only-property-accessor-in-c

Comment: I was positive it was a dupe, just couldn't find it...

Comment: I _was_ going to close this as a dupe, but the answer given is sufficiently different from answers in the "dupe" question that _I_ think it should stay. Up to the community, now....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You won't be able to use an autoproperty.

```
public class SomeClass()
{
    private List<string> someList;
    public IList<string> SomeList { 
        get { return someList.AsReadOnly(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: According to MSDN, this operation is O(1), so no need to worry about the performance hit.

Comment: The only problem being that modifying the internal list will cause enumerations to fail.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that IList needed to be used (but didn't have AsReadOnly() as a method). This seems to be the "best" bet so far; still feels wrong, though.

Comment: @John Gietzen: This only applies if they happen to call methods on you while holding an enumerator, or you have multithreaded code.

Comment: @Michael - what makes it feel wrong? You can implement add and delete methods if necessary. This way, you control modification to the list

Comment: @Michael Todd: What feels "wrong" about it? The "returning a read-only version of the list" is the whole point of the `AsReadOnly()` method.

Comment: Oh, I guess I've just become too complacent. I've been using { get; set; } for so long that doing it another way feels like a workaround. You're right, though, it's fine.

Comment: If he had an IList instead of a List the he could use new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(someList). The AsReadOnly() is a nice wrapper for the List class.

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to return the list as a [ReadOnly list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75.aspx).  You can do this with the following code:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public ReadOnlyCollection<string> GetList() {
    return SomeList.AsReadOnly();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Return `IEnumerable<string>`, which is immutable. The getter should look like this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> SomeList
{
   get
   {
      foreach(string s in someList) yield return s; // excuse my inline style here, zealots
      yield break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Although a bit more involved than the AsReadOnly route, I like this implementation a bit better

Comment: This does prevent random access on the list, though.

Comment: You're right, Anon, but I always figure that to require random access is to have some knowledge about the collection. Any external caller to this method could only be making assumptions about the collection it gets back, which I prefer not to allow it to do.

Comment: I don't quite understand what's going on here. Is the property `SomeList` reading from itself in its own getter? Isn't that circular?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SomeClass()
{
    private List<string> _someList = new List<string>();

    public IList<string> SomeList 
    { 
         get { return _someList.AsReadOnly(); } 
    }
}
```