# C# prevent dictionary property elements from being set outside class?

Tags: c#, properties, encapsulation

Title says it all. Reducing access through access modifiers only prevents reinitialising the property; It doesn't prevent elements from becoming global state (bad practice). I know there's a [workaround with `List<T>`'s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158160/prevent-other-classes-from-altering-a-list-in-a-class) but what should I do for any other indexed collection?

```
public class Start
{
    public static void main()
    {
        //CODE SMELL AHEAD
        AttendanceManager.MuteStatuses[0] = new KeyValuePair <string, string> ("", ""); 
    }
}

public static class AttendanceManager
{ 
    public static HybridDictionary MuteStatuses
    {
        get
        {
            playersMuteStatuses.Add ("", "");
            return playersMuteStatus;
        }
    }      
    private static HybridDictionary playersMuteStatus = new HybridDictionary();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont use `HybridDictionary`. We do have `IReadOnlyDictionary<T>`

```
private Dictionary<string, string> playersMuteStatus = new... ;
public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> MuteStatuses
{
    get
    {
        return playersMuteStatus as IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write helper methods:

```
public static void AddMuteStatus()
    => playersMuteStatus.Add("", "");

public static object GetMuteStatus(object idx)
    => return playersMuteStatus[idx];
```