# Prevent list element access from outside class c#

Tags: c#, .net, list

As what might be a continuation of this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158160/prevent-other-classes-from-altering-a-list-in-a-class)

I stepped into the need of having a list of class `List<Foo>` where I would like to restrict the access to the elements of the list, but not the access to the list as a whole, so that I can get/set the whole list, but not get/set any of its elements.

The challenge is that the type of the elements of the list needs to be a public class with all its members (that are properties) public due to serialization of the list elements.

Is there any way to implement this?

Thanks in advance

Edit:

I attempted this:

```
public class SomeClass()
{
    private List<string> someList;
    public IList<string> SomeList { 
        get { return someList.AsReadOnly(); }
    }
}
```

And checked if there could be any method that provides my need that would be kind of `get { return someList.AsWholeListGettable&SettableOnly(); }` or `get { return someList.AsNoAccessibleElementsList(); }`

I also tried the [] operator overload to try to make the index operator kind of private. (The same behaviour for an array would also be accepatable).

```
class SampleCollection<T>
{
    // Declare an array to store the data elements.
    private T[] arr = new T[100];

    // Define the indexer to allow client code to use [] notation.
    private T this[int i]
    {
        private get { return arr[i]; }
        private set { arr[i] = value; }
    }
}
```

as in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/).

So that from outside the class members wont be accesible. But I get this error:

[image]

Comment: Please, share your code and attempts to solve the problem

Comment: Can you define in code what you don't want to be able to do? I think that will help to improve the question :-)

Comment: How is this list going to be populated/ maintained? Just on Construction?

Comment: Set or get as a whole, with innaccesible elements from the outside. My approach would be a CustomArray or CustomList which get an standard array/list in contruction, and which indexer operators are private or overriden to achive the behaviour desired. But cannot achieve that with my attemps and dont know if its even possible in c#...

Comment: for me it's still not clear what you want to prevent: is it: `collection[0].SomeProperty` you want to deny?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Holy smokes, I am posting the answer in case it could be useful for anyone.
Setting the index property as private behaves as I need:

```
    class SampleCollection<T> {
        // Declare an array to store the data elements.
        private T[] arr = new T[100];

        // Define the indexer to allow client code to use [] notation.
        private T this[int i] {
            get { return arr[i]; }
            set { arr[i] = value; }
        }
    }
```

My problem was that I was double setting as private the property and the accessor so that's why I was getting the error. Below the error producing code:

```
    private T this[int i]
    {
        private get { return arr[i]; }
        private set { arr[i] = value; }
    }
```

Setting the index property private, you lock the access to the index of the list so the elements cannot be got or set, and you can handle the whole list elements bulk handling with other methods. Thats what I wanted.

Comment: Hi, if this is your answer, you should mark it as well ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to be able to adjust the values of the properties of the list's contents, you basically have 2 options:

1) use elements which are immutable, e.g.:

```
public class YourElementType
{
    private readonly string _bar;
    public YourElementType(string bar)
    {
        _bar = bar;
    } 

    //no set, so no change
    public string Bar get { return _bar}
}
```

2) return a copy of the objects when returning the list. The object copies themselves are mutable, the original list won't be.

```
public class SomeClass()
{
    private List<YourElementType> someList;

    public IList<YourElementType> SomeList { 
        get 
        { 
            return someList.Select(t => new YourElementType() 
            {
                // ...initialize to create a copy
            }).ToList().AsReadOnly(); 
         }
    }
}
```

Do note: it's expensive in memory and in CPU performance.

---

As from your comment, it seems you want something like:

```
public class SomeClass()
{
    private List<YourElementType> someList;

    public IEnumerable<YourElementType> SomeEnumertor { 
        get 
        { 
            return someList.AsIEnumerable(); 
         }
    }
}
```

You can loop it, in a `foreach`, but `SomeEnumertor[0]` is not possible. A user could again wrap it in a lit btw.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need the list elements to be mutable, and would like to have the compiler prevent the programmer from accesing the list or array member in compilation, as if they had private behaviour. That is what I meant with "but not get/set any of its elements" regarding the access.

Comment: `prevent the programmer from accesing the list or array member in compilation`, can you show in an example, in your question, what you actually want to prevent? The exact detail is of the essence here I think ;-)

Comment: The point would be that myArray[0] or myList(0) threw a compilation error kind of: "index not accesible due to its protection level", as when you are trying to access a class private field from the outside. I want to make the elements NOT accesible. Hope that make sense

Comment: Nice. That achiveves what I want!. So when you want to pass through classes reference to a set of elements but not allow access through indexes, this is what should be used, right? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I expected that there could be a more concrete way to manipulate a set of types as an inaccesible whole element, also preventing access to the elemetns even with the foreach, and taking into account the instance scope, or public private accessors, but this solution does the work.

Comment: Anyhow I think that the indexer operator overload solution would not be a possible solution to what I want, is it? Thanks for any comments on that @Stefan

Comment: Well, it might be a nice exercise,  I think it should be possible. But I am afraid you'll end up with a fuly customized class, which might not be worth the effort. Besides, there are interfaces out there with this purpose, if IEnumerable works for you, its best to just use it because you'll get all the benefits of the framework that comes with it :)

Comment: alright! I might just ask that in a new question. Thanks a lot :)